# TypeScript error when replacing mongoose's mpromise library with global.Promise

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

I use promises with Mongoose, which usually throws up a deprecation warning for the internal mpromise library Mongoose uses.

The workaround given in [most](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38138445/node3341-deprecationwarning-mongoose-mpromise) [places](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4291) is to replace Mongoose's promise library with native Promises, like this

```
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise
```

However since converting my project to TypeScript my IDE (VS Code) now throws an error saying

```
message: 'Type 'Function' is not assignable to type 'typeof Promise'.
  Property 'fulfilled' is missing in type 'Function'.'
```

[image]

How could I fix this?

Comment: workaround (<any>mongoose).Promise = global.Promise;