# (node:2157) DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated, plug in your own promise library instead

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm using MEAN stack and every time I save an user i get this warning

(node:2157) DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated, plug in your own promise library instead: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html

this is where I save user data

```
user.save(function(err, user) {
    if (err) return res.status(500).send({message: There was an error creating user. Please try again later: ${err}})
    return res
      .status(200)
      .send({ message: 'user successfully created' });
  });
```

what should I do to delete warning in console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38138445/node3341-deprecationwarning-mongoose-mpromise) answer.

You need to plugin a promise library (q, bluebird, the es6 one...)

For `bluebird`:

```
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
```

For es6:

```
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
```

More information you can find in [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html).