# Passing external variable in function Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm passing the URL into the function to connect to `mlab`.

This is my function :

```
function connectToDb(mongoURL) {
    mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

    mongoose.connect(mongoURL, (err, db) => {
      err ? console.log(err) : console.log('Connected mongoose');
    });
}
```

I call the function connectToDb in another function :

```
function getURL(){
 connectToDb(mongoURL);
}
```

ERROR :

> (node:1380) DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default
>   promise library) is deprecated, plug in your own promise library
>   instead: http://mongoo

Comment: Did you check this:: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38138445/node3341-deprecationwarning-mongoose-mpromise

Comment: I guess, it's a warning, and before execution `connectToDb` function, `mongoose.Promise` is `mpromise` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this error should have been solved by the latest updates. if you're using mongoDB 3.6.2 or later, and mongoose 5.0.0. However if you are using an older version of mongoose and don't want to update, you can plug in your own promise library. [reference](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html)

This warning can also be resolved if you add

```
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
```

after requiring mongoose but before connecting to db.