# NestJS - Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated

Tags: node.js, mongoose, promise, nestjs

Getting this very well known warning :

> (node:15304) DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's
>   default promise library) is deprecated, plug in your own promise
>   library instead: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html

The usual fix is to use a Promise library like Bluebird instead :

```
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
```

(Edit) or `mongoose.Promise = global.Promise`, but according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38138445/node3341-deprecationwarning-mongoose-mpromise) and [this post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/278778/why-are-native-es6-promises-slower-and-more-memory-intensive-than-bluebird), Bluebird is 4 times faster than ES6's native Promise

However, in Nest, we're not including Mongoose directly. We include Nest's own `@nestjs/mongoose` module (which internally, imports Mongoose).

```
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

@Module({
    controllers: [AdsController],
    imports: [ MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://localhost/nest') ]
})
```

Therefore `mongoose` is undefined so I can't attach Bluebird to it.

How to inject Bluebird in Mongoose when using NestJS?

Comment: What do you mean "the usual fix"? If you read blog posts from 2010 maybe. Try `mongoose.Promise = global.Promise` in most "modern" nodejs environments which support promises right out of the box.

Comment: and `import * as mongoose from 'mongoose'`. You only need to set the promise library once in the whole application code. nodejs will only import modules once.

Comment: If you refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38138445/node3341-deprecationwarning-mongoose-mpromise), using Bluebird would be 4 times faster than `mongoose.Promise = global.Promise`

Comment: @NeilLunn, apparently that did the trick. I imported `mongoose`, then defined `mongoose.Promise`, then imported `@nestjs/mongoose` and the deprecation warning disappeared. If you write that as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks :)

Comment: and [another thread for you to read](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/278778/why-are-native-es6-promises-slower-and-more-memory-intensive-than-bluebird).

Comment: @NeilLunn please consider posting your comment as an answer.

Comment: @JeremyThille by the way, bluebird is now ~1.5 times faster than native promises - especially when using the builtin promise APIs. There is work done on making native promises faster in Node. If you have any specific use case you'd like to share with us we'd love to hear it. (disclosure, I'm a core member in both bluebird and Node).

Comment: No real specific use case - I'm just experimenting and trying to implement Mongoose in Nest, and oddly enough, it's way harder than I expected